# MS Word: File -> "Edit Property" to change author not listed

Tags: microsoft-word, metadata, editing

I'd like to edit the author name in a Word doc. I go to "Info," right-click the author name, but "Edit Property" is not listed.  What to do?

(running Professional Plus 2016 on Windows 10)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my method isn't as good as Charles', but here's what worked for me:

Options -> General -> Personalize your copy of Office

Now type in the new author name in place of the old one.

**The key to getting this to work:**

Save the document with a new name.

Answer (score -1):

### Simplest method is to insert the Author Document Property Content Control in your document.

You can find this under `Insert > Quick Parts > Document Property`.

Insert this content control anywhere, change it and delete it. This is linked directly to that property.

Here is [my page on these quasi-document properties](https://addbalance.com/word/MappedControls.htm#PageStart) as well as the ones that are not linked to Content Controls.

This is considered an Advanced Property and you may have a button to open those in your File Information tab.

### Because I often look at these, I put a link to open the dialog on my QAT.

Here is a [thread on the Microsoft Answers site](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/qat-button-for-advanced-properties-dialog/067e584e-988a-4c3b-97b0-9de743145e89) describing the location of that control. It is the  `View Document Properties` in the dialog for QAT modification.

Comment: There are two authors.  I would like to remove the second one and replace it with a different name.  I went to ``Insert > Quick Parts > Document Property` and chose "aughor."  It inserted the primary author's name at the top of the file.  Can't figure out how to change author #2.  Also, I wonder why I can't edit via File ->Info-> right-click "author."

Comment: With the Document Property, change it and list both. I do not use SharePoint and cannot really address what it is you need to do to change it through File > Info.

Comment: I don't use Sharepoint and know nothing about it.  I don't understand the step-by-step, and am confused about the multiple authors.